# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare(). Add contact in contact list android

Tags: java, android

I want to create a code that adds a contact to the android contact list without any prompts, but I get this exception. If you have another idea how I could add a contact to the contact list without any window appearing please share with me. I'm new to java, so please if you want to help show me an example or correct my code.

My cod:

```
class ContactAdd extends Activity 
{
    private String FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber;
    private Context mContext;

    public ContactAdd(String First, String Last, String Phone, Context context)
    {
        this.FirstName = First;
        this.LastName = Last;
        this.PhoneNumber = Phone;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> AddContactInList()
    {
        final ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> contacts = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        final int rawContactInsertIndex = contacts.size();
        SharedPreferences preference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        contacts.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, preference.getString("accountKey",null))
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, preference.getString("emailKey",null)).build());

    //Add Name
    contacts.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,0 )
            .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, FirstName+" "+LastName)
            .build());


    //Add Phone Number
    contacts.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, PhoneNumber)
            .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
            .build());

    return contacts;

    }
}


public class Contact 
{
    public static void addContact(Activity pyActivity, String name, String phone, String email)
    {
        ContactAdd Contact = new ContactAdd(name, name, phone, pyActivity.getApplicationContext());
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> contacts = Contact.AddContactInList();
        try {
            ContentProviderResult[] res = pyActivity.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, contacts);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
jnius.jnius.JavaMethod.__call__
10-22 11:40:22.245 32726 32753 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 1045, in jnius.jnius.JavaMethod.call_staticmethod
10-22 11:40:22.246 32726 32753 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_utils.pxi", line 91, in jnius.jnius.check_exception
10-22 11:40:22.246 32726 32753 I python  :  jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: Can't create handler inside thread Thread[SDLThread,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare() java.lang.RuntimeException
```

I would also try this code, it works but a confirmation window appears

```
public class Contact{

    public static void addContact(Activity pyActivity, String name, String phone, String email){
        Uri contactUri = Uri.parse(String.format("tel: %s", phone));

        Intent i = new Intent(Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT, contactUri);
        i.setType(Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
        i.putExtra(Intents.EXTRA_FORCE_CREATE, true);
        i.putExtra(Intents.Insert.NAME, name);
        i.putExtra(Intents.Insert.PHONE, phone);
        i.putExtra(Intents.Insert.EMAIL, email);
        pyActivity.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: `I would also try this code, ` That code looks ok. And for the rest i cannot help you, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

> > public ContactAdd(String First, String Last, String Phone, Context context)

For what this constructor?

You cannot start an Activity with the `new`operator.

Activities have to be created using an intent.

If you do not need the functionality of an activity there then do not extend from Activity.

Comment: I'm not claiming this to be correct, I'm just looking for a way to add a contact to the android contact list without prompt. I also try this code, it work but with prompt



Uri contactUri = Uri.parse(String.format("tel: %s", phone));
Intent i = new Intent(Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT, contactUri);
i.setType(Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
i.putExtra(Intents.EXTRA_FORCE_CREATE, true);
i.putExtra(Intents.Insert.NAME, name);
i.putExtra(Intents.Insert.PHONE, phone);
pyActivity.startActivity(i);

Comment: yes sir @blackapps